# Add SQL Server configuration in .NET Core app project with Docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core

I follow this tutorial to set up docket with VueJS (Quasar), docker and SQL Server:

https://dev.to/quasar-pt-br/qpanc-parte-2-postgresql-51pb

I want to use SQL Server instead of PostgresSQL.

How can we set up a SQL Server database (localDB) with docker in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: ASP.NET Core on a different platform than windows does not support LocalDB.

You can start SQL Server in a container according to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-powershell). You can then connect from your asp.net core container. This is the way I'm developing on a mac.